# merge lines from several files

Tags: batch-file, sed, grep

I have 3 text files like this

**file1.txt**

```
AAA1
AAA2
AAA3
...
...
```

**file2.txt**

```
BBB1
BBB2
BBB3
..
..
```

**file3.txt**

```
CCC1
CCC2
CCC3
..
..
```

I want to have **output.txt** like this

```
AAA1:BBB1:CCC1
AAA2:BBB2:CCC2
..
...
```

now I can do this by making a loop reading a line from each file but I want to do this using sed , grep or any similar tools but I dont know how.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [paste](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/paste/):

```
paste -d ':' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`paste` is well suited to this task. Try:

```
paste -d ":" file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The paste answer sounds like a perfect solution.

But someone (not the OP) might want a native solution that does not require downloading an executable. Something like this really should be done with a more powerful scripting language like VBScript or JScrpt.

But, since I like the challenge of solving things with batch, I thought I'd take a stab at a native batch solution, just for fun.

The OP said *"now I can do this by making a loop reading a line from each file"*. That is easier said than done using batch!

Normally files are read using FOR /F, but there is no good way to interleave reads from multiple files using FOR /F. The only other native alternative is to use SET /P with redirected input. This technique imposes the following limitations:

- The input files must use Windows style line terminators: `<carriage return><line feed>`
- No input line can exceed 1021 bytes in length (disregarding the line terminators)
- Trailing control characters are stripped from each input line

In addition, each final merged line must not exceed the batch variable length limit of ~8k bytes.

One last restriction - the script can only handle up to 7 input files. The script will fail if more than 7 files are specified - I did not include any error checking.

So here is a working batch script - call it "merge.bat". *Note - this batch solution is MUCH slower than other solutions like paste or scripts written in VBScript or JScript. But it does work :-)*

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

::Initialization
set "inputRedirection="
set "files=2"
set "lines=0"
for %%F in (%*) do call :setInputRedirection
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "inputRedirection=!inputRedirection:::=<!"

::Merge the files
%inputRedirection% (
  for /l %%N in (1 1 %lines%) do (
    set "ln="
    for /l %%I in (3 1 %files%) do (
      call :readLine %%I
      if %%I neq %files% (
          set "ln=!ln!!input!:"
      ) else (
          echo(!ln!!input!
      )
    )
  )
)
exit /b

:setInputRedirection
set /a "files+=1"
for %%A in (1) do (
  set inputRedirection=%files%::"%%~F" %inputRedirection%
  for /f %%N in ('find /c /v "" ^<"%%~F"') do if %%N gtr %lines% set "lines=%%N"
)
exit /b

:readLine  fileHandle
set "input="
<&%1 set /p "input="
exit /b
```

To merge your files you would do:

```
merge.bat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt >output.txt
```

Comment: great answer, to be honest I didn't think that its going be complicated as thought but you are right , but I did know that its going to be a long code and that's why I did chose use paste , but your code is very useful for me because now I learned a new way of doing it , thanks